# multiple ::setTimer in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I need more than one timer using the ::SetTimer function having the same EventID. Is this possible/a good idea to create multiple window handles with ::CreateWindow, and then assign each timer to the created window handles? Any other choices?

---

**Edit:** Anyway, I only want to know what happens here:

```
int eventID = 0;
hWnd1 = ::CreateWindow(...);
hWnd2 = ::CreateWindow(...);
::SetTimer(hWnd1, eventID, ...);
::SetTimer(hWnd2, eventID, ...);
```

Does every hWnd has it's own eventID list? and do they get handled independently? I don't want to discuss whether this design makes sense or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The timer identifier, nIDEvent, is
>   specific to the associated window.
>   Another window can have its own timer
>   which has the same identifier as a
>   timer owned by another window. The
>   timers are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same EventID you should be able to make do with the same timer but at different intervals. You can simply kill the old one with [KillTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then create another one with [SetTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which triggers more or less often. If you have a situation where this isn't possible then quite likely there is a flaw in the design of your program.

Consider using different EventIDs and give us some more info about why you feel doing it this way is necessary. You most likely don't want to go about creating random windows if they are only going to serve the purpose of having timer messages registering to them. This sounds like a messy hack which will yield unnecessary computation and inefficient overhead.

Of course a timer does not actually require you to associate a hWnd with it. The hWnd is optional and you can instead associate your timer with a callback ( lpTimerFunc ).

Comment: I didn't want to use different EventIDs because I'd have to increment them after every instantiation, so it might overflow :) And I also have to kill,set them independently. That means it's not possible to do that if you omit the hWnd with the same EventID, right? So I thought I'd create a new hWnd which probably has its own event list..

Comment: Maybe it's easiest to just go for a global increment variable and hope it doesn't overflow.... after a few hundert years hehe :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you think might overflow ?

Comment: My timer is in a base class and gets recreated all the time. So I need to generate new EventIDs every time a new instance is created. Using a global counter to get new EventIDs might overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want two windows? You can set two timers in one window. You can identify which timer is fired, using the the ID parameter of WM_TIMER handler (OnTimer() in MFC). Please consider this way if you're not really required high precision timer.

Comment: Thx for your comment. Yes I know I could do that. As I said in a previous comment, the timer is in a base class. So do you suggest to make one window static and use a global increment variable to generate EventIDs for every instance of this class? seems a bit strange to me :)